# Recycler view notifyDataSetInvalidated() equivalent

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I am changing my existing List View to Recycler View and am trying to create the corresponding Recycler View adapter. In my current list view adapter there is a method called notifyDataSetInvalidated() being used. what would be equivalent call for recycler view in order to invalidate data.

Comment: what's the functionality of notifyDataSetInvalidated()??? is it used to refresh adapter data??? if so, on recycler view, u can do that using notifyDataSetChanged() method.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171077/notifydatasetchanged-vs-invalidatedata - for the difference.

Answer (score 0):

NotifyDataSetInvalidated equivalent will be two option.

Refresh UI from the adapter:

```
mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); // When dataset of adapter changed
```

or refresh it from recyclerView itself:

```
recyclerView.invalidate(); // When adapter or its component changed
```

In recyclerView there are many other opportunity. You can check this: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html

Comment: according to this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23171077/notifydatasetchanged-vs-invalidatedata it says they are different. can you explain how is it same?

Comment: I just modified my answer. The difference is invalidate reinitialize full adapter and  notifyDataSetChanged reinitialize data.@Ramya