# android listview updates only sometimes

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a listview in my android program that gets its information from an ArrayList adapter. 
I have three methods that call listview.invalidateViews().

Two of these methods work without fail, and the third seems to freeze the listview. The information is correctly saved when backing out of the activity and on a screen rotate. But without taking these actions, the listview does not update.

Any Ideas?

UPDATE:

These instances work:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int index, long id) {
    al.remove(index);
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public void addToList(View view) {
    EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.ListText1);
    if (et.getText().toString().equals("")) {
        //do nothing
    }
    else { 
        al.add(et.getText().toString());
        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        et.setText(null);
    }
}
```

This method does not work:

```
public void resetList(View view) {
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: are you just changing the view or the content of the list view? if you are changing the data of list view use notifydatasetchanged method

Comment: I am updating the content of the list. adapter.notifydatasetchanged() appears to do the same thing.

Comment: you might want to read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676720/is-there-any-difference-between-listview-invalidateviews-and-adapter-notify)

Comment: Ive changed all instances of listview.invalidateViews() to adapter.notifydatasetchanged(). The same problem occurs

Comment: Yeah, two of the instances of notifydatasetchanged() work as they should, and the third is giving me the same problem.

Comment: Added code to question

Comment: in resetlist what do you want to do exactly?

Comment: It should empty the arraylist. Ive also tried a for loop to remove() all the entries in the arraylist, but the same problem occurs.

Comment: why dont you use al.clear();?

Comment: You are my favorite person today. The simplest solution wins. Do you know why that would work and bringing in a new object would not?

Comment: ill explain it to my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are using `invalidateViews()` differently, if you want to change the view of the `listview's child` then you can use the `invalidateViews()` but if you are changing the data/content of the `listview's adapte`r you need to use `notifyDataSetChanged()` method.

the difference of the two are discussed in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10676720/is-there-any-difference-between-listview-invalidateviews-and-adapter-notify)

**ListView.invalidateViews()**

```
 is used to tell the ListView to invalidate all its child item views (redraw them). Note that there not need to be an equal number of views than items. That's because a ListView recycles its item views and moves them around the screen in a smart way while you scroll.
```

**Adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()**

```
on the other hand, is to tell the observer of the adapter that the contents of what is being adapted have changed. Notifying the dataset changed will cause the listview to invoke your adapters methods again to adjust scrollbars, regenerate item views, etc...
```

and with your method

```
public void resetList(View view) {
    al = new ArrayList<String>();
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

making a new object of `ArrayList<String>();` will not reset the data of your list view. just because the `al` ArrayList that you passed on your adapter is now different to your  `al = new ArrayList<String>();` what you need to do now is to access your current arraylist then clearing its content with `al.clear()` method.