# how set text color in custom ListView

Tags: android, listview, colors, cell

i have problem with setting color per each cell in ListView. Im using custom ListView:

```
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
```

my adapter:

```
public ListViewAdapter adapter;
ListView listView=(ListView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView1);
            list=new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
            LayoutInflater inflater1 = getActivity().getLayoutInflater();
            View header = inflater1.inflate(R.layout.naglowek_wlasne_spolki, listView, false);
            listView.addHeaderView(header);
```

my method to adding item to list:

```
public void add_stock(String name,double actual_price,double amount,double medium_price){
    HashMap<String,String> temp=new HashMap<String, String>();


    temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, name);
    temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, Double.toString(actual_price));
    temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, Double.toString(medium_price);
    temp.put(FOURTH_COLUMN, amount);
    list.add(temp); 

}
```

I have problem with coloring each cell's text.
This is my xml code for this listview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/nazwa_spolki"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"
      android:textStyle="bold" />  

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/wartosc_akt"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/wartosc_kupna"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_weight="0.5" />

  <TextView 
      android:id="@+id/wartosc_calosci"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:textStyle="bold"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

adapter implementation:

```
public class ListViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HashMap<String, String>> {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list;
private Activity activity;
public static final String FIRST_COLUMN="First";
public static final String SECOND_COLUMN="Second";
public static final String THIRD_COLUMN="Third";
public static final String FOURTH_COLUMN="Fourth";


public ListViewAdapter(Activity activity,ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list){
    super(activity, R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, list);
    this.activity=activity;
    this.list=list;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.size();
}

@Override
public HashMap<String, String> getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}



@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
        listViewHolder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
        listViewHolder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
        listViewHolder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
        listViewHolder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    listViewHolder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));

    return convertView;
}

public class ListViewHolder {
    TextView txtFirst;
    TextView txtSecond;
    TextView txtThird;
    TextView txtFourth;
}

}
```

Comment: You want to change the color of the text, or the cell's background color? Also, could you post your implementation of the adapter?

Comment: color of the text in cell, i also added implementation of the adapter.

Comment: Is there a particular reason to use ListViewHolder? Are you using it somewhere elsewhere? I'll be posting an answer soon.

Answer (score 0):

This code allows you to set the color dynamically with `listView.getAdapter().setColor()`

```
    private int mColor = Color.Black.;

    public setColor(int color)
    {
        mColor = color;
    }

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
        listViewHolder.txtFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
        listViewHolder.txtSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
        listViewHolder.txtThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
        listViewHolder.txtFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);
        convertView.setTag(listViewHolder);
    } else {
        listViewHolder = (ListViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
    listViewHolder.txtFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
    listViewHolder.txtFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));


    TextView textViewFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
    TextView textViewSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
    TextView textViewThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
    TextView textViewFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);

    textViewFirst.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewSecond.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewThird.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewFourth.setTextColor(mColor);

    return convertView;
    }
```

Note that after setting the color, the contents of the ListView may have to be refreshed. Use `listView.getAdapter().notifyDataSetChanged()` to do this. You may also use `listView.invalidateViews()` , you can see the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10676754/3811891).

In case you don't need `ListViewHolder`:

```
private int mColor = Color.Black.;

public setColor(int color)
{
    mColor = color;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ListViewHolder listViewHolder;
    boolean firstUse = false;

    if(convertView == null){
        listViewHolder = new ListViewHolder();
        convertView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.lista_wlasnych_spolek, null);
        firstUse = true;
    } 

    TextView textViewFirst = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki);
    TextView textViewSecond = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt);
    TextView textViewThird = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna);
    TextView textViewFourth = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci);

    if(firstUse)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> map=list.get(position);
        textViewFirst.setText(map.get(FIRST_COLUMN));
        textViewSecond.setText(map.get(SECOND_COLUMN));
        textViewThird.setText(map.get(THIRD_COLUMN));
        textViewFourth.setText(map.get(FOURTH_COLUMN));
    }

    textViewFirst.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewSecond.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewThird.setTextColor(mColor);
    textViewFourth.setTextColor(mColor);

    return convertView;
}
```

EDIT:

The answer above is about coloring all of the entries.

To set the color of TextView-s inside a chosen entry, you need to get the currently used view from a given position of the entry. Use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24864536/3811891) to learn how to do this. You can paste the given function in the class where you are creating and using `listView`.

After you get the view, you can set the color like this:

```
LinearLayout root = (LinearLayout)getViewByPosition(position);
    ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.nazwa_spolki)).setTextColor(mColor);
    ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_akt)).setTextColor(mColor);
    ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_kupna)).setTextColor(mColor);
    ((TextView) root.findViewById(R.id.wartosc_calosci)).setTextColor(mColor);
```

And finally, don't forget to refresh with `notifyDataSetChanged()` or `invalidateViews()` if needed.

Comment: Ok, it works great! but i still don't know how to change color text in cell I want.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize that you want to change a particular entry. I'll update the answer when I get home.

Comment: it works, but im trying to update this datas every 30 sec, and i have another problem when i change color of the cells after a while the color restores to defalt value. Do you know why?